# What is the difference between "Java subtype" and "true subtype"

Tags: java, subtype

I've just now encountered the phrases "java subtype" and "true subtype". It was given in a question in a way that makes clear that they are **not** the same. But I couldn't find an explanation on what is the difference between the two.

Can someone please explain the differences between "java subtype" and "true subtype"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A java subtype is any class that extends another class (or even implements an interface). A true subtype is not something language specific:

A true subtype can always be substituted for the supertype.
"Any property guaranteed by supertype must be guaranteed by subtype (true subtyping)"

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse331/10au/lectures/subtypingexamples.pdf

The link contains a very enlightning example. Let's say you have a class Point2D that stores values x and y. You could now create a subtype Point3D and add a value z. If you don't override any methods and take care with your equals and hashcode methods you could substitute a Point3D instance at any time for a Point2D instance.

This is a simple example of course. One could argue why not have only Point3D. Maybe the classes both offer some methods that can - by dividing up into to classes - be better recognized as belonging to the 2D or 3D realm. In this case it would probably be purely a design decision.

```
class Point2D {
   int x;
   int y;
}

//true subtype
class Point3D extends Point2D {
   int z;
}
```

A more complex example might arise if you take a Person class and then have two subtypes: Employee and Customer. Both Employee and Customer offer all the same fields and methods as a Person.

```
class Person {
   String name;
   Date birthday;

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o){
       //simplified equals implementation, this does not fulfill equals contract!
       return name.equals(((Person)o).name);
   }
}

//true subtype, same behaviour
class Employee extends Person {
   long departmentId;
}

//not a true subtype, different behaviour -> equals
class Customer extends Person {
   long customerId;
   Date lastContact;
   String city;

   public boolean equals(Object o){
       //simplified equals implementation, this does not fulfill equals contract!
       return customerId.equals(((Customer)o).customerId);
   }
}
```

In this example Employee would be a true subtype of Person. However Customer is not a true subtype because the equals implementation differs (and presumably hashCode() as well) and it would not behave the same and could probably not be substituted for a Person object at all times.

Comment: If you have two types which can always be substituted for each other, its unclear to me why you have two types in the first place.

Comment: Does it mean that a true subtype will return the same output for the same input as the super class returns, but that Java subtype will return a different result for a method of the super class with same input?

Comment: in the link i posted is a nice example. true subtyping is a rather theoretical construct. i'll add to the answer, to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I googled this page. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-170-laboratory-in-software-engineering-fall-2005/recitations/recitation5.pdf

The distinction sound rather technical and not very useful.

Answer (score -1):

See the image which explains the difference.

[image: Java Subtype Vs True Subtype]

In that the class **Human** has the similar behavior of the class **Vertebrate** even if it is not using **extends** or **implements** keywords. This is called **True Subtype**. Whereas the class **Squid** is extending the class **Vertebrate** using **extends** keyword which is called **Java Subtype**.

Comment: Why Squid isn't a true subtype of Vertebrade?

Comment: It is a subtype which is called java subtype because you are using java key words. I also don't know where can we use it practically.

Comment: the first one is not true sub type because you should pay attention that the @effects annotation in the vertebrate class the method should return value >0 but the inheriting class returns 0 which makes it weaker than the original class!